# How do I style a dynamically added control?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

In the PreInit event(Have also tried Load event), I am dynamically adding custom user controls at runtime based on conditions in the back end. My problem is that the user control added to the page does not take on the theme the site is currently set to, and is using the default styles for all the controls within it.

How do I go about fixing this? I'm having a hard time finding anything particularly relevant using google.

Answer (score 2):

bunch of ways to do that.

```
MyControl.Attributes.Add("class", "myclass")
MyControl.Style.Add("background-color", "red")
MyControl.Attributes("bgcolor") = "lightblue"
```

Comment: Sorry I think I need to elaborate. I am making use of the asp.net skin/theming feature. I already have skins set up for all the controls. If the controls are on the page from design time, they render with their appropriate theme/skin/styles etc. If I load the controls at runtime, they render as the default. Is there any way to apply my theme on the new control without specifically adding attributes?

EDIT: Figured it out, please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. My site saves the current theme into a session variable on the initial load. After I have dynamically added my controls to the page, I use the session variable to re-apply my theme. My dynamically added controls then take on the appropriate theme.

Answer (score 0):

Try to divorce your ASP.NET controls from their styling as much as you can.  Using CSS classes will allow you to do this easily.  You didn't post code samples so I can only guess what your custom controls look like.  They likely have some form of container like a div.  Determine which layer will handle you CSS class structure, add an asp:Literal to that layer of the markup, then expose the Text property of the Literal as a public property of the control.  At runtime when you create and add the control to the Controls collection, you can assign the proper class name for the scenario.

It would look something like this:

```
<div class="<asp:Literal ID="uxCssClassLiteral" runat="server" />">
    <p>My content goes here</p>
</div>
```

From code behind

```
public class MyControlType
{
    public string CssClass 
    {
        get { return this.uxCssClassLiteral.Text; }
        set { this.uxCssClassLiteral.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

The page would handle the control like this:

```
public class MyPage 
{
    protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyControlType controlA = new MyControlType();
        if (condition1 == true)
        {
            controlA.CssClass = "class-name-for-condition-1";
        }
        else 
        {
            controlA.CssClass = "class-name-for-other-condition";
        }
        this.Controls.Add(controlA);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris, 
Thank you for your feedback. I have already resolved the issue and posted my solution above. The way our skins work is that we use CSS classes as far as possible and link those into our skin. The reason for this is that we found skins create inline styles, which is a no-no. Our skins only have properties set for things that can't be set in CSS, other than that, they just link to our CSS classes.

Once again, thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: No problem, you posted your answer while I was typing mine. I've used ASP.NET themes before and found them to work up to a certain point and then they fall on their face. I'm very curious where you found CSS falling short and themes capable of going further. If you are trying to get web forms styling out of your application, I suggest you look at [CSSFriendly](http://cssfriendly.codeplex.com/).  They are a set of control adapters that help render ASP.NET controls in a much more div orientated manner without all the nested tables and inline styles that are normally rendered.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I don't visit here often unless I'm stuck with something I couldn't solve via extensive googling :P

On topic, its not so much any shortcoming of CSS itself. Simply put, we keep a track of which skin/theme a client uses in our database, and load it via our server-side code. I'm pretty sure its not the absolute best method, but for our current purposes it works. In future we may look into another method if necessary.

Comment: I wouldn't change working architecture just to be "pure", but if/when you decide to go after a more CSS-centric approach, the easy way of handling this is to turn on/off which CSS files are loaded in the header.  You can do this with literals, placeholders, or just touching the link tags in code-behind. Use a central CSS file for your shared layout/style and then add to it each theme implementation in a separate file.